# I'm trying to make a McDonalds menu, what's wrong with the code i'm using?

Tags: python

```
theOrder = input(f"Hello, welcome to McDonald's, what can i get for you today? \n")


McRoyal = 19.99
McChicken = 9.99
    
if str(McRoyal) in theOrder:
    print(f"that would be {str(McRoyal)}")
else:
    print("that's not on the menu")
```

I have two options, either McRoyal or McChicken..

If i try to type "McRoyal" it doesn't give me the price, but tell me it isn't on the menu

Comment: It's a simple and useful debugging tool - to print your intermediate data. Try to `print(str(McRoyal))` before condition, and think why it prints what it does

Comment: For the record, the proper approach is to have a dictionary (`dict` or `{}` literal) to hold both the names and prices of all items.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because you're trying to check if the string representation of McRoyal (which is "19.99") is in the input order string. Instead, you should check if "McRoyal" is in the input order string.

Here's the corrected code:

```
theOrder = input("Hello, welcome to McDonald's, what can I get for you today?\n")

McRoyal = 19.99
McChicken = 9.99

if "McRoyal" in theOrder:
    print(f"That would be ${McRoyal}")
elif "McChicken" in theOrder:
    print(f"That would be ${McChicken}")
else:
    print("That's not on the menu")
```

Answer (score 1):

it's important to understand the distinction between datatypes and variables.

In this context, we have two variables, namely `McRoyal` and `McChicken` which are placeholders pointing to specific values, which are 19.99 and 9.99, respectively. These values are of the datatype called `float`.

Now, let's discuss type casting. When you use type casting, such as `str(McRoyal)` within the condition `if str(McRoyal) in theOrder:`, you are essentially converting the float value `19.99` into a string. The result of this type casting operation is the string `'19.99'`. It's essential to note that this string representation is not equivalent to the original float value; they are distinct.

If you want to efficiently manage these items and their prices, a more suitable approach is to use dictionaries. In a dictionary, you can store the items ('McRoyal' and 'McChicken') as keys and their respective prices (19.99 and 9.99) as values. This makes it easier to work with and calculate the total price without the need for explicit type casting.

**CODE:**

```
items = {'McRoyal': 19.99, 'McChicken': 9.99}
total_price = 0
for name, price in items.items():
    if name in theOrder:
        print(name, price)
        total_price += price
print(total_price)
```